# html5 rocks node js server-sent-events SSE example not working

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, server-sent-events

link to article: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

The node.js SSE server is not working in that example.  I end up with an open connection to `/events`, but no response is received by the browser.

[image: Chrome dev-tool prnt scrn]

**sse-server.js**

```
var http = require('http');
var sys = require('sys');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  //debugHeaders(req);

  if (req.headers.accept && req.headers.accept == 'text/event-stream') {
    if (req.url == '/events') {
      sendSSE(req, res);
    } else {
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.end();
    }
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/sse-node.html'));
    res.end();
  }
}).listen(8000);

function sendSSE(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
  });

  var id = (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString();

  // Sends a SSE every 5 seconds on a single connection.
  setInterval(function() {
    constructSSE(res, id, (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString());
  }, 5000);

  constructSSE(res, id, (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString());
}

function constructSSE(res, id, data) {
  res.write('id: ' + id + '\n');
  res.write("data: " + data + '\n\n');
}

function debugHeaders(req) {
  sys.puts('URL: ' + req.url);
  for (var key in req.headers) {
    sys.puts(key + ': ' + req.headers[key]);
  }
  sys.puts('\n\n');
}
```

**sse-node.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    var source = new EventSource('/events');
    source.onmessage = function(e) {
      document.body.innerHTML += e.data + '<br>';
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note the article is from 2010, so I am guessing that there is something that has changed in node since then that is making this not run.  I am using node v.10.18

Comment: I just tested, with v0.10.28 and is working..

Answer (score 3):

The problem was with the server. In my case I was using node with IIS using the iisnode node package. To solve this, I needed to configure iisnode in the web.config like so:

```
<iisnode flushResponse="true" />
```

After this, everything worked fine. Others with a similar issue may start here, but apache and nginx may have similar configuration requirements.

Comment: -1 for misleading answer to probably different problem with similar symptoms. As was pointed by @rahpuser original question was about "node.js server naked" without any redundant garbage like IIS or Apache

Answer (score 1):

Why did you comment out the res.end() at the end of the sendSSE function? That's the method that actually sends the response to the browser.

Comment: Sorry, that was left over from my debugging attempts.  Original code from example posted now.

Comment: I downloaded it and it works for me. Maybe the issue is with your node configuration?

Comment: I too notice that the example works with `res.end()` inserted, but doing that would seem to defeat the purpose of Server-Sent Events. So I'm not sure what's up.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

I already try that code and is working for me, as you are not using ngnix, or any other server as proxy for your node instances I would believe that the problem is with your machine, if you have firewall or anti virus running, stop it, and try again or any other software that could be intercepting yours req and res.

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis Excuse me, what did you mean? I saw your answer and is about server config.

Comment: because the issue was server config, in particular, iis

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis sorry Matthew, I got confused, alnafie is not talking about any server.. he has the node.js server naked with out a robust server on top of node ( As nginx or iis ). He is just using >node server.js in command line or well that was my understanding, because of that is not a real server, and is more like a machine configuration ( firewall, anti virus, games that may he has installed, etc.), so don't worry I wasn't copying your answer neither was my intention. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have saved the HTML file with same name as described sse-node.html in same directory. Other thing might be make sure 8000 port is open in your local machine no one is using it. or change the port and re-run sse-server.js. its working for me as is.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Nothing wrong with your code just **Provide Full Resource Address** in your HTML File.

```
var source = new EventSource('http://localhost:8000/events'); //true way
```

**instead of**

```
var source = new EventSource('/events'); //improper way
```